# problem in passing parameter <xsl:for each

Tags: c#, xslt

I am passing parameter from C# to xsl in `<xsl: for each>` but I am not getting the output.
Here is my code till now

```
<xsl:param name="xpath" select="sessions/session"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$xpath"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($xpath)">
```

And transformed whith

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
XsltArgumentList xsArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xslt.Load(strXstFile);

//creating xpath through some logic , it is working fine 
xsArgs.AddParam("xpath", "", xpath);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII);
StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(ms);
xslt.Transform(doc, xsArgs, writer);
```

I am checking the values through  and values are passing perfectly as I want but when I am using t hem in xsl:foreach it is not displaying the results I expected.Earlier when I was not using exsl:node-set it was throwing error so I used it but I guess it is making my string something else.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your sample seems incomplete. Where do you use for-each? And what error did you get before using exsl?

Comment: sorry Idk y it was not showing but now as u see I basically wants to do filtering based on xpath value . I was getting error "Expression must evaluate to a node set" If I m using $xpath alone without exsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are under the misapprehension that you can set a parameter or variable to a string and then use that string as an XPath query.  You cannot.

This:

```
<xsl:param name="xpath" select="sessions/session"/>
```

creates a parameter named `xpath` and sets it, by default, to a node-set.  Since the context node is the root, the node-set will only contain anything if the top-level element of the input document is named `sessions` and it has at least one `session` child element.

Here's what `$xpath` doesn't contain:  an XPath expression.

If, in your C# code, you set the parameter to a string containing an XPath expression, then instead of containing a node-set, it will contain a string.  This:

```
<xsl:value-of select='$xpath'/>
```

will emit that string, and this:

```
<xsl:for-each select='exsl:node-set($xpath)'>
```

will do nothing, since the `node-set` function expects its argument to be a result tree fragment, and `$xpath` contains a string.

I'd bet that what you really want to do is something more like this:  change the name of the parameter from `xpath` to something less misleading, like `nodeset`, and create the node-set in your C# code:

```
xsArgs.AddParam("nodeset", "", doc.SelectNodes(xpath));
```

Comment: Dynamically evaluating an XPath expression seems possible with the ("experimental") extension function `dyn:evaluate(strXPathExpression)`. See http://www.exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/index.html

Comment: yah you are rite Robert thats what I was doing wrong . I was assigning string to the parameter but you are rite I need to create the node-set in my C# code..its working fine now ....Thanks a lot....